# Error in putting ImageView component within View component

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

When I'm putting ImageView component within View component, I am getting the error: **Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.** I don't understand what is wrong over here. Below is the code snippet:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Modal, Text } from 'react-native';
import styles from './cameraStyles';
import ImageView from "react-native-image-viewing";

export default ({captures=[], lflagImage=false}) => {
    const [flagImage, setflagImage] = React.useState(lflagImage);
    return (
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} style={[styles.bottomToolbar, styles.galleryContainer]}>
            {captures.map(({ uri }) => (
                <View style={styles.galleryImageContainer} key={uri}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> {setflagImage(prevData => !prevData)}}>
                        <Image source={{ uri }} style={styles.galleryImage}/>                       
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <ImageView
                        images={captures}
                        imageIndex={0}
                        visible={flagImage}
                        onRequestClose={() => setflagImage(prevData => !prevData)}
                    />
                </View>
            ))}
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra set of braces within your TouchableOpacity's onPress event. It should be:

```
onPress={()=> setflagImage(prevData => !prevData)}
```

This could be causing the issue you are experiencing.

I also can't see what styles.galleryImage is, but make sure you are defining a height and width or else it won't display anyway.